# VRaptor - Guice Creation Errors

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa, vraptor

i cant understand why this error dont go away i tryed several things like using all version of hibernate-entitymanager, adding the vraptor-jpa 1.0, but nothing works:

ERROR:

```
21:58:20,041 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /vraptor/: com.google.inject.CreationException: Guice creation errors:

1) No implementation for javax.persistence.EntityManager was bound.
  while locating javax.persistence.EntityManager
    for parameter 0 at vraptor.UsuarioDao.<init>(UsuarioDao.java:14)
  at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.guice.GuiceComponentRegistry.bindToConstructor(GuiceComponentRegistry.java:151)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:435) [guice-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:154) [guice-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106) [guice-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:95) [guice-3.0.jar:]
    at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:83) [guice-3.0.jar:]
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.guice.GuiceProvider.start(GuiceProvider.java:97) [vraptor-3.5.3.jar:]
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.init(VRaptor.java:119) [vraptor-3.5.3.jar:]
    at br.com.caelum.vraptor.VRaptor.init(VRaptor.java:113) [vraptor-3.5.3.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.getFilter(ManagedFilter.java:69) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta30.jar:1.0.0.Beta30]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta30.jar:1.0.0.Beta30]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.0.Beta30.jar:1.0.0.Beta30]
...
```

The IndexController.java:

```
package vraptor;
    import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Path;
    import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Post;
    import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Resource;
    import br.com.caelum.vraptor.Result;

    @Resource
    public class IndexController {

      private final Result result;
      private final UsuarioDao userDao;

      public IndexController(Result result, UsuarioDao userDao) {
        this.result = result;
        this.userDao= userDao;
      }

      @Path("/")
      public void index() {}

      @Post @Path("/cadastro")
      public void cadastro(Usuario usuario){


          //System.out.println(usuario);

          this.userDao.InsertUser(usuario);
          this.result.forwardTo(IndexController.class).index();
      }
    }
```

the UsuarioDAO

```
package vraptor;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import br.com.caelum.vraptor.ioc.Component;


@Component
public class UsuarioDao {

    //private EntityManager em = new EntityManagerCreator().getInstance();

    private EntityManager em;

    public UsuarioDao(EntityManager em){
        this.em = em;
    }

    public void InsertUser(Usuario usuario) {
        try{
            this.em.persist(usuario);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the Usuario.java

```
package vraptor;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;


    @Entity
    public class Usuario {

        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private long idUsuario;
        private String nome;
        private String sobreNome;

        public long getIdUsuario() {
            return idUsuario;
        }

        public void setIdUsuario(long idUsuario) {
            this.idUsuario = idUsuario;
        }

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }

        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }

        public String getSobreNome() {
            return sobreNome;
        }

        public void setSobreNome(String sobreNome) {
            this.sobreNome = sobreNome;
        }
    }
```

the persistence:

```
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="default" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>vraptor.Usuario</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="12345"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/teste"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      <property name="hibernate.show.sql" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.format.sql" value="false"/>
   </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>modelo0</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelo0</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.com.caelum</groupId>
    <artifactId>vraptor</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.3</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer here:

[Upgrade vRaptor to 3.5.3 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/caelum/vraptor/validator/Validator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21605298/upgrade-vraptor-to-3-5-3-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-br-com-caelum-vraptor-v)

```
from: @andregnhoato (Brasileiro LINDO DO MEU CORAÇÃO)

Figured out what was happening with the upgrade process. I'm using the project, a jar that manages instances of EntityManager vraptor-jpa, when I kept the update, it occasioned the error. Compatibility could be:

vraptor in version 3.4.2, use the plugin vraptor-jpa-4.0.0.jar

vraptor in version 3.5.3, the plugin uses vraptor-jpa-1.0.1.jar

This change was enough to solve the problem.
```